# CSS - Formatar uma tabela

Tags: css, tabela-html

Tenho uma tabela que tem um cabeçalho bem complexo e não estou conseguindo estilizar, as linhas da tabela ficam com uma altura maior nos campos que ficaram com 2 linhas, como posso arrumar isso ?

Segue o link do [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/acq168b0/5/)

Obrigado!

**EDIT:** e preciso tambem que as linhas da tabela fique bem longas, mesmo sem dados dentro, será q é mais facil fazer linhas verticais e horizontais em divs com css doq usando tabelas ?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Execute o código abaixo e veja funcionando:

```css
.inANDout table {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-spacing: 0px;
    border-collapse: separate;
    margin: 0 auto;
    color: #595c62;
    font-size: 0.6em;
    font-family: 'verdana';
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}

.inANDout table .top td, .inANDout table .dados:last-of-type td{
  border-bottom: 2px solid #595c62;
 
}
.inANDout table td{
  border-left: 2px solid #595c62;
  padding:1em;
}
.inANDout table td:first-of-type{
  border-left: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="inANDout">
 <table>
  <tr class="top">
   <td class="inANDoutOpcoes">Opções</td>
   <td class="inANDoutTipo">Tipo de Valor</td>
   <td class="inANDoutTotal">Valor Total</td>
       <td class="inANDoutParcelas">Nº de Parcelas</td>
   <td class="inANDoutAtual">Parcela Atual</td>
   <td class="inANDoutValor">Valor da Parcela</td>
   <td class="inANDoutData">Data de Saída/Entrada</td>
  </tr>
    <tr class="dados">
      <td class="dadosOpcoes">X Y Z</td>
    <td class="dadosTipo">R$</td>
    <td class="dadosTotal">150,00</td>
    <td class="dadosParcelas">3</td>
    <td class="dadosAtual">1</td>
    <td class="dadosValor">50</td>
    <td class="dadosData">08/09/2015</td>
   </tr>
            <tr class="dados">
    <td class="dadosOpcoes">X Y Z</td>
    <td class="dadosTipo">R$</td>
    <td class="dadosTotal">150,00</td>
    <td class="dadosParcelas">3</td>
    <td class="dadosAtual">2</td>
       <td class="dadosValor">50</td>
    <td class="dadosData">08/10/2015</td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </div>
```

Veja também [neste Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/acq168b0/8/)

Para linhas grandes, adicione `line-height`, exemplo:

```
/* PARA LINHAS GRANDES */
.inANDout table .dados td{
  line-height:160px;
}
```

Veja [neste Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/acq168b0/9/).

Comment: certinho!! vlw!!